# Running multiple spiders through CrawlerRunner. Not able to store the output in a JSON file

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am using a CrawlerRunner to run multiple spiders one after another. I want to save the result in a JSON file, but I am not able to do so.

```
CODE(try.py)
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
import scrapy

class MySpider1(Spider)
#defining class

class MySpider2(Spider)
#defining class            

class MySpider3(Spider) 
#defining class

class MySpider4(Spider)
#defining class

configure_logging()

runner = CrawlerRunner()

runner.crawl(MySpider1)

runner.crawl(MySpider2)

runner.crawl(MySpider3)

runner.crawl(MySpider4)

d = runner.join()

d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

reactor.run()
```

All the classes have yield methods.

I am running the script with this command:

```
scrapy runspider try.py -o i1.json
```

which yields the correct output on the conda prompt but an empty `i1.json` is created 
but when I run the spider in individual files,then i obtain the json file with proper content.

So how can I store data in JSON file when running multiple spiders together?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your question and code to make it more legible so that others can help you more easily.

Comment: And the last paragraph of your question is unclear. Can you correct that so that others can understand where exactly the problem is?